# Rails says "password can't be left blank" but password was inputted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Whenever I try to create a new user, I get an error message saying that the "password cannot be left blank" but there was content in the password form before submission.

Here is the form that's inside **application.html.erb**:

```
  <div class="signup_form_div">
    <h1>Create an account!</h1>
    <%= form_for(:user, :url => {:controller => 'users', :action => 'create'}) do |f| %>
      <p class="text_fields">
        <%= f.text_field :first_name, placeholder: 'First Name' %>
        <%= f.text_field :last_name, placeholder: 'Last Name' %>
        <%= f.text_field :username, placeholder: 'Desired Username' %>
        <%= f.text_field :email, placeholder: 'Email Address' %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: 'Password' %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, placeholder: 'Confirm Password' %>
      </p>
      <p id="signup_submit">
        <%= f.submit :Signup, class: 'button'%>
      </p>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

This is the **users_controller.rb** file:

```
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new( user_params )
    logger.debug user_params
    if @user.save 
      flash[:notice] = "You've signed up successfully"
      flash[:color] = "valid"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Form is invalid"
      flash[:color] = "invalid"
    end
    render "new"
  end


  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :first_name, :last_name)
  end
```

and this is at the top of the **user.rb** model file:

```
  attr_accessor :password

  #validation of form input
  has_secure_password
  EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[^@\s]+@([^@.\s]+\.)+[^@.\s]+\z/
  validates :username, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :length => { :in => 3..20 }
  before_save { :email.downcase }
  validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => { case_sensitive: false }, :format => EMAIL_REGEX
  validates_length_of :password, :in => 6..20, :on => :create
```

Heres the log from trying to create a user with name "John Doe", user "jdoe", email "jdoe@email.com", and password "password1":

```
Started POST "/create" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-17 13:22:58 -0400
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"B+5wtiVRnM4kqFi5/MN8dTtSYkV+ppZXrM+7YekAMJw=", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"John", "last_name"=>"Doe", "username"=>"jdoe", "email"=>"jdoe1@email.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Signup"}
{"username"=>"jdoe", "email"=>"jdoe1@email.com", "password"=>"password1", "password_confirmation"=>"password1", "first_name"=>"John", "last_name"=>"Doe"}
  [1m[35m (0.3ms)[0m  BEGIN
  [1m[36mUser Exists (0.4ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  1 AS one FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`username` = BINARY 'jdoe' LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mUser Exists (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`email` = 'jdoe1@email.com' LIMIT 1
  [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mROLLBACK[0m
  Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 72ms (Views: 9.4ms | ActiveRecord: 3.8ms)
```

Let me know if theres any other files needed to help.
Thanks

Comment: add your `params` and the output of `user_params` in the log file

Comment: @Babar I've added this to the original post.

Comment: Have you tried creating the user from console?

Comment: I'm very new to rails development.  Would that be done by doing this `User.create :username => "jdoe", :password => "password1", :password_confirmation => "password1", :first_name => "John", :last_name => "Doe", :email => "jdoe@email.com"`?

Comment: @cmlewis95 Yes you can do by this command from terminal. :)

Comment: @cmlewis95 if you want, you can give me your Skype id and I can look at it on your pc.

Comment: @Babar Im on my way out the door right now but if I don't get it solved by later today I might take you up on that. I had it working all day yesterday and this morning and I'm not sure what changed but  I refreshed the page and it no longer worked

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the `@user` object in your form.

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
```

Notice `:user` => `@user`. Also rails will know whether to `POST` or `PUT` based on if the `@user` object is a new record or old, it can do this by calling `.new_record?` on the `@user` object.

Comment: When I change the first line of the form to `<%= form_for(@user, :url => {:controller => 'users', :action => 'create'}) do |f| %>` I get an error that says "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty"

Comment: In your `def new` action make sure you instantiate a new `User` object. `@user = User.new`

Comment: I don't think it should make any difference @liamneesonsarmsauce, if he is directly using URL option in form_builder

Comment: It matters doing rails the right way since he said he's new to this. Does the user already exist in your DB?

  `[1m[36mUser Exists (0.4ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  1 AS one FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`username` = BINARY 'jdoe' LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mUser Exists (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`email` = 'jdoe1@email.com' LIMIT 1`

Comment: @liamneesonsarmsauce yup, he is new and should follow the proper convention, sorry my bad.

Comment: Also, the ruby on rails documentation says "You must pass the name of an instance variable, i.e. :person or "person", not an actual instance of your model object."  So doesn't this meant that it should be `:user` and not `@user`?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the need for the `@use`r in the `form_for` tag (as indicated above), the form itself needs to be in a specific location.

In your question you say the form in in application.html.erb, which is not the correct location.

In the case of a new user the form needs to be in
app/views/users/new.html.erb

The controller should be in
`app/controllers/users_controller.rb`  (not user_controller.rb)

you should also have something like this in your `config/routes.rb`

```
resources :users
```

assuming you have your routes setup correctly then when a GET request comes to /users/new it will get routed the the new method of your `users_controller.rb`, which will create a new instance of a user and then make that available to your `new.html.erb` view.

Comment: I have a sticky navigation bad at the top of the site that I wrote the HTML for inside of `application.html.erb`. It occurs on the top of every page of the entire site. If this is the incorrect location to do something like that, where should it go? I added the `@user` to `form_for` which produced an error on page load. I don't have `resources :users` in the `routes.rb` file though, would that be causing problems even if I have the right gets/posts?

Comment: layouts/application.html.erb, is fine for headers, footers, or anything else you want on every page, but not for a form such as this.  You don't want this form on every page, right?  I think the specific issue you are having can be fixed using my answer above (ie put the corrected form in the right location and use the correct file name/location for the controller),  but I think if you want to learn rails take a look at this http://www.railstutorial.org/book

Comment: Ill definitely check that book out, thanks.  The way I have my navigation bar set up is that if `session[:user_id]` does not exist, then the navigation bar has a button that says "Login" and when clicked, drops down a section that has the login form.  If `session[:user_id]` does exist, then it displays the user's username and when clicked drops down links to get to profile, account settings, etc.

Comment: Also, I have an identical form located at `users/create` and when I have everything set up as suggested on here, I still get the "Password cannot be blank" error

Comment: normally a redirect to a signup page would work ie get users/new, but if you want to do it this way, I think the problem is that you just don't have a user object created.  are you using '@user' in the form_for ? Where do you check the session[:user_id]?  maybe in that point you can create a new user   ie '@user = User.new'

Comment: I changed it back to `:user` and removed the `attr_accessor :password` line and the signup form works from both locations now.  However, the login form is now broken.  I assume that `attr_accessor` is needed for something but I don't have a full understanding of what it does.  Does this help you understand the issue at all?